# parsing with the json data Error: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to parse the Json. I have put the image of the json structure. Please have a look.

The error I'm receiving is:

```
print("title: "+json_data["title"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My JSON structure is as follows:

```
[
    [
        {
            "title": "What you need to know",
            "snippet": "+128.2.207.79; path=/resources/useful-links/43-what-<B>you</B>-<B>need</B>-to-<B>know</B>-amy\nLast-Modified: Sun, 18 Mar <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> \n\n Urinary stress incontinence is common after delivery; in fact, some All <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor\n\tFrequently Asked Questions\n\tGlossary\n\tUseful links\n\n\n\tNews it!\tTheir story\n\n\n\tBlogs\tThe Oops! Team’s\n\tFrom the Experts\n\n\n\tResources\tVideos\n\tInfo Sheets\n\tAll <B>you</B>",
            "id": "clueweb12-1007wb-23-25678",
            "url": "174.142.68.174",
            "score": 13.533853530883789
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "title": "What you need to know ",
            "snippet": "  What <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> (Jessica)  \n\n\n\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\n\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n   \n    Share <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> \n\n Sports involving jumping or impact have a direct effect...\n\n\n The Oops! team's blog\n\n \n\nVideos Info sheets All <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor it!\tTheir story\n\n\n\tBlogs\tThe Oops! Team’s\n\tFrom the Experts\n\n\n\tResources\tVideos\n\tInfo Sheets\n\tAll <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor\n\tFrequently Asked Questions\n\tGlossary\n\tUseful links\n\n\n\tNews\tPress",
            "id": "clueweb12-1007wb-27-29239",
            "url": "174.142.68.174",
            "score": 13.533853530883789
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "title": "What you need to know",
            "snippet": "+128.2.207.79; path=/component/content/article/46-what-<B>you</B>-<B>need</B>-to-<B>know</B>-\nLast-Modified: Sat, 17 <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor\n\tFrequently Asked Questions\n\tGlossary\n\tUseful links\n\n\n\tNews <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B>...\n\n\n The Oops! team's blog\n\n \n\nVideos Info sheets All <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor <B>need</B> to <B>know</B>\n\nFor more information",
            "id": "clueweb12-1006wb-19-18957",
            "url": "174.142.68.174",
            "score": 13.533853530883789
        }
    ],
    {
        "hasmore": 1,
        "numhits": 1000
    }
  ]

]
```

While the code I'm using is:

This is the code of where I load the json data.

```
#assigning path to the url variable
url = link of the server 
#Taking response and request  from url
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
#reading and decoding the data
data = json.loads(r.read().decode(r.info().get_param('charset') or 'utf-8'))


for json_inner_array in data:
        for json_data in json_inner_array:
                    print("title: "+json_data["title"])
                    print("snippet: ", json_data["snippet"])
                    print("id: ",json_data["id"])
                    print("url: ",json_data["url"])
                    print("score:",json_data['score'])
```

Comment: You aren't using `json.loads` to parse the string into a dictionary.

Comment: used the Json.load

Comment: What @JimFasarakisHilliard said, or `data` doesn't have the structure you think it does. Add `print(json_inner_array)` before the inner for loop to see what the second loop is actually iterating over.

Comment: "used the Json.load" Edit your question and show us how you've used it. At this point, the code snippet you've provided does not show any usage of the `json` library.

Comment: please check the code again

Comment: One thing is sure: if you get this message, then at this point `json_data` IS a string. And FWIW `json` refuses to parse the json snippet you posted. Please post a proper MCVE

Comment: hi, it print the output given below. itle: What you need to know (Susan)
snippet:  +128.2.207.79; path=/component/content/article/46-what-<B>you</B>-<B>need</B>-to-<B>know</B>-susan
Last-Modified: Sat, 17 <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about 

For more information
id:  clueweb12-1006wb-19-18957
url:  174.142.68.174
score: 13.533853530883789                                                             program run  but crash in the middle .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of that final `dict`:

```
{
    "hasmore": 1,
    "numhits": 1000
}
```

Your inner loop is expecting to process lists containing dicts, and so when it hits that dict it attempts to do `json_data["title"]` on the "hasmore" key.

Here's a repaired version.

```
import json

datastring = r'''
[
    [
        {
            "title": "What you need to know (Amy)",
            "snippet": "+128.2.207.79; path=/resources/useful-links/43-what-<B>you</B>-<B>need</B>-to-<B>know</B>-amy\nLast-Modified: Sun, 18 Mar <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> (Amy)\n\n Urinary stress incontinence is common after delivery; in fact, some All <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor\n\tFrequently Asked Questions\n\tGlossary\n\tUseful links\n\n\n\tNews it!\tTheir story\n\n\n\tBlogs\tThe Oops! Team\u2019s\n\tFrom the Experts\n\n\n\tResources\tVideos\n\tInfo Sheets\n\tAll <B>you</B>",
            "id": "clueweb12-1007wb-23-25678",
            "url": "174.142.68.174",
            "score": 13.533853530883789
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "title": "What you need to know (Jessica)",
            "snippet": "  What <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> (Jessica)  \n\n\n\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\n\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n   \n    Share <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> (Jessica)\n\n Sports involving jumping or impact have a direct effect...\n\n\n The Oops! team's blog\n\n \n\nVideos Info sheets All <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor it!\tTheir story\n\n\n\tBlogs\tThe Oops! Team\u2019s\n\tFrom the Experts\n\n\n\tResources\tVideos\n\tInfo Sheets\n\tAll <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor\n\tFrequently Asked Questions\n\tGlossary\n\tUseful links\n\n\n\tNews\tPress",
            "id": "clueweb12-1007wb-27-29239",
            "url": "174.142.68.174",
            "score": 13.533853530883789
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "title": "What you need to know (Susan)",
            "snippet": "+128.2.207.79; path=/component/content/article/46-what-<B>you</B>-<B>need</B>-to-<B>know</B>-susan\nLast-Modified: Sat, 17 <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor\n\tFrequently Asked Questions\n\tGlossary\n\tUseful links\n\n\n\tNews <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B>...\n\n\n The Oops! team's blog\n\n \n\nVideos Info sheets All <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor <B>need</B> to <B>know</B>\n\nFor more information",
            "id": "clueweb12-1006wb-19-18957",
            "url": "174.142.68.174",
            "score": 13.533853530883789
        }
    ],
    {
        "hasmore": 1,
        "numhits": 1000
    }
]
'''

data = json.loads(datastring)

for json_inner_array in data:
    if isinstance(json_inner_array, list):
        for json_data in json_inner_array:
            print("title: "+json_data["title"])
            print("snippet: ", json_data["snippet"])
            print("id: ",json_data["id"])
            print("url: ",json_data["url"])
            print("score:",json_data['score'])
```

**output**

```
title: What you need to know (Amy)
snippet:  +128.2.207.79; path=/resources/useful-links/43-what-<B>you</B>-<B>need</B>-to-<B>know</B>-amy
Last-Modified: Sun, 18 Mar <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> (Amy)

 Urinary stress incontinence is common after delivery; in fact, some All <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor
        Frequently Asked Questions
        Glossary
        Useful links


        News it!        Their story


        Blogs   The Oops! Team’s
        From the Experts


        Resources       Videos
        Info Sheets
        All <B>you</B>
id:  clueweb12-1007wb-23-25678
url:  174.142.68.174
score: 13.533853530883789
title: What you need to know (Jessica)
snippet:    What <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> (Jessica)  




















    Share <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> (Jessica)

 Sports involving jumping or impact have a direct effect...


 The Oops! team's blog



Videos Info sheets All <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor it!        Their story


        Blogs   The Oops! Team’s
        From the Experts


        Resources       Videos
        Info Sheets
        All <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor
        Frequently Asked Questions
        Glossary
        Useful links


        News    Press
id:  clueweb12-1007wb-27-29239
url:  174.142.68.174
score: 13.533853530883789
title: What you need to know (Susan)
snippet:  +128.2.207.79; path=/component/content/article/46-what-<B>you</B>-<B>need</B>-to-<B>know</B>-susan
Last-Modified: Sat, 17 <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor
        Frequently Asked Questions
        Glossary
        Useful links


        News <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B>...


 The Oops! team's blog



Videos Info sheets All <B>you</B> <B>need</B> to <B>know</B> about your pelvic floor <B>need</B> to <B>know</B>

For more information
id:  clueweb12-1006wb-19-18957
url:  174.142.68.174
score: 13.533853530883789
```

---

If you need to read the data in that final dict, just add an `else` block. Eg,

```
for json_inner_array in data:
    if isinstance(json_inner_array, list):
        for json_data in json_inner_array:
            print("title: "+json_data["title"])
            print("snippet: ", json_data["snippet"])
            print("id: ",json_data["id"])
            print("url: ",json_data["url"])
            print("score:",json_data['score'])
    else:
        print("\nExtra info:")
        print("hasmore:", json_inner_array["hasmore"])
        print("numhits:", json_inner_array["numhits"])
```

Comment: @AbhishekKaushik Any chance you can change the JSON you get back (or request that it be changed)? The JSON would be much cleaner to parse if each value in an array has the same type.

Comment: @AbhishekKaushik I agree with chepner, if you can get that JSON structure changed, you should do! IMHO, the outer level should be a dict, not a list. That dict can contain a dict for the extra info and a list of the main data dicts, there's no need for each of those dicts to be wrapped in its own 1-item list.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, But I can't change the structure as I got it from someone else for performing some experiments.. I was finding difficulty in this Json. The structure is not very clear. Thanks everyone for all your help and support.